# How can I use a for loop to output a bool

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have been trying to use a for loop to check whether an element exists inside an array. I cannot seem to figure out how to do this as all variables declared inside the for loop cannot be accessed from outside its scope. How might I go about doing this properly?

```
var array = new[] { 3, 4, 2, 6, 3 };
var value = 2;

bool isContained;
for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    isContained = (value == array[i]);

if(isContained)
    Console.WriteLine("The value is in the array");
else
    Console.WriteLine("The value is not in the array");
```

Comment: `var isContained=array.Any(x=>x==value)` dont need for loop

Comment: @LucianBumb `Contains()` would be better still, but it would also be important to understand why the above code didn't work.

Comment: @JonHanna - `Any()` works in `any` situation. If tomorrow he will try to look for an `object` in an `object[]` he will discover that `Contains()` is not the easy way :)

Comment: @LucianBumb by that logic, use a `for` loop.

Comment: One basic technique that would allow to resolve 95% of issues like that by yourself is using debugger. Learn to use it, step through your code, understand what it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides the fact that as it is, your code won't even compile because `isContained` may never be initialized, the problem is that you would keep overwriting `isContained` over and over again in the `for` loop:

```
bool isContained;
for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    isContained = (value == array[i]);
```

Basically, you need to set it if and only if you've found the correct value. So a basic working version would be:

```
bool isContained = false;
for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (value == array[i]) isContained = true;
}
```

Clearly, once a match is encountered, it makes no sense to iterate over the rest of the array. Hence this is slightly better:

```
bool isContained = false;
for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (value == array[i])
    {
        isContained = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

This is a good approach to understand the concept. However, as someone pointed out in the comments, a more advanced solution exists that is a 'one-liner':

```
bool isContained = array.Any(x => x == value);
```

Comment: That's not the problem that stops it compiling, it's that it could conceivably (with an empty array) not get set at all that causes CS0165.

Comment: @JonHanna Yeah, you are right. Didn't notice it won't even compile.

Comment: thanks a bunch, I understood that it could be done with the .Any or .Contained method but I just wanted to understand fundamentally what was wrong with the statement for future reference

Comment: @AidenTemere That's a good approach. You should learn and understand how things work using the basic constructs of the language. At the end of the day, you will better understand high-level methods like `Any` and other LINQ constructs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `isContained` value gets overwritten inside each iteration. Your code should be written as follows:

```
Boolean isContained = false;

for (Int32 i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
{
    if (value == array[i])
    {
        isContained = true;
        break; // no need further processing, you found it
    }
}
```

On a side note... why not just using [Enumerable.Contains()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
Int32[] array = new Int32[] { 3, 4, 2, 6, 3 };
Int32 value = 2;

if (array.Contains(value))
    Console.WriteLine("The value '{0}' has been found in the array!", value);
```

Or a `LINQ` solution as follows:

```
Int32[] array = new Int32[] { 3, 4, 2, 6, 3 };
Int32 value = 2;

if (array.Any(x => x == value))
    Console.WriteLine("The value '{0}' has been found in the array!", value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try returning from inside the loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if(value == array[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The value is in the array");
        return;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("The value is not in the array");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has three problems.

The first is that the compiler can't detect that `isContained` will definitely be assigned. Consider if the array was empty; then `isContained` would never be set and it's not legal to use a value that hasn't been set. The compiler has to be relatively local in what it looks at to determine if a value has been set (if it could be cleverer we'd end up with cases that were very hard for us to work out why they were allowed or not), so that's a no-no.

And of course if it did happen that the array was empty, we should have a result anyway, which should be `false`.

We can solve both of those problems by starting off with the value set to `false`:

```
var array = new[] { 3, 4, 2, 6, 3 };
var value = 2;

bool isContained = false;
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    isContained = (value == array[i]);

if (isContained)
    Console.WriteLine("The value is in the array");
else
    Console.WriteLine("The value is not in the array");
```

And it gives us the wrong answer, revealing the third problem; because `isContained` keeps being written over it only tells us the last answer. One way to fix this is to use `|=` so that it can set false to true but not true to false:

```
var array = new[] { 3, 4, 2, 6, 3 };
var value = 2;

bool isContained = false;
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    isContained |= (value == array[i]);

if (isContained)
    Console.WriteLine("The value is in the array");
else
    Console.WriteLine("The value is not in the array");
```

This works, but is wasteful. Once we know the value is in the array it doesn't matter if we look at 0, 2, or a billion more values; the answer is going to be true. So we should stop looking:

```
var array = new[] { 3, 4, 2, 6, 3 };
var value = 2;

bool isContained = false;
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (value == array[i])
    {
        isContained = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (isContained)
    Console.WriteLine("The value is in the array");
else
    Console.WriteLine("The value is not in the array");
```

This gives us the correct answer quicker.

Incidentally a simpler version worth knowing about is to use `Contains()` which is for asking just these sort of questions:

```
if (array.Contains(value))
    Console.WriteLine("The value is in the array");
else
    Console.WriteLine("The value is not in the array");
```

Or more generally `Any()` which can ask more flexible questions about a collection:

```
if (array.Any(x => x == value))
    Console.WriteLine("The value is in the array");
else
    Console.WriteLine("The value is not in the array");
```

Being able to loop explicitly yourself though remains a vital technique to know. It's also the fastest, though the difference is so slight as to only matter in tight loops: Continue learning with `for` loops until you are confident with them, but then use the more concise and self-explanatory `Contains` or `Any` when applicable except in performance-critical points.

Answer (score 1):

Though you asked for a for loop, an infinite while may be better. Personally, I find the while loop a bit more expressive and explicit.  The notion, or premise that while the loop iterates, it will stop once a match has been found.

Where in my mind the for loop can function almost identically, but that explicit while this is being performed, a explicit action will follow.  Where the for loop quickly, iterate through a collection, then an action will follow.

Mostly in a phrasing manner, or quick glance, you would quickly assume intent.

```
int index = 0;
int value = 9;
bool valid = false;

while(collection.length != index)
{
     if(value == collection[index])
     {
          valid = true;
          break;
     }

     index++
}
```

You could also achieve this with Linq, which is more expressive.

```
int value = 9;
var valid = collection.Any(item => item == value);
```

Personally I find the any and while to be more expressive and self documenting for your use case.

Comment: Your `while` loop isn't infinite (`while(true)` would be)... But *why* would it be *better*? You can `break` from a `for` loop just the same and I'd argue intent is more clear with a `for` loop, especially when iterating a collection by index (or better, a `foreach` if the index is incidental such as this case and you don't mind the minimal overhead incurred due to the enumerator)

Comment: Those are fair, personally I find for each, while, and Linq a bit more expressive or quicker.  You’re correct, I usually call while loops infinite loops often cause if you write it incorrectly it will become infinite, not sure that’s proper terminology.  If it isn’t I’ll edit.

Comment: My point was that you say "it may be better" but you don't say *why* it might be better

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Can you read my changes, want to make sure it is helpful.

Comment: You still have an issue with your while loop. If the array doesn't contain the value being searched for you will get an index out of bounds exception. Your while loop needs to not only test your flag variable but it must also have bounds checking added to it. While that's entirely an option, I personally don't see why you'd pick it over a for/foreach for this particular task.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I corrected, wasn't paying attention.  I'm so a custom to using `.Last()` or Linq that I spaced.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot seem to figure out how to do this as all variables declared inside the for loop cannot be accessed from outside its scope

What do you mean? Your code has problems, but none involve not being able to access variables declared inside the `for` loop.

The code you posted should be close to compiling successfully. It does have a couple of problems though:

1. The main one is that you don't initialize `isContained`. This will cause the compiler to emit CS0165, "Use of unassigned local variable". Declared the variable with an initialization: `bool isContained = false;`.
2. Also, you keep setting `isContained`, so what you get at the end is really just whether the *last* element in the array is what you're looking for. Try `isContained |= (value == array[i]);` instead, or something like:

```cs
if (value == array[i])
{
    isContained = true;
    break;
}
```

That's a little more verbose than just using the `|=` operator, but it does terminate the loop early.

Of course, if you just want to get the value, and aren't trying to learn how to write a loop like that, you can use the built-in [`Enumerable.Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
bool isContained = array.Contains(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered to death... However

> Here is a plethora of ways to to achieve what you want, its good to
>   understand all these variants as they will become the bread and butter
>   of just about every algorithm you design in the future

Given these variables

```
var array = new[] { 3, 4, 2, 6, 3 };
var value = 2;
var isFound = false;
```

You can use a `for` loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) // loop to the end of the array
{
    if (array[i] == value) // comparison
    {
        isFound = true;    // we found
        break;             // We can exit the loop early
    }
}

// Write our results
Console.WriteLine($"Found = {isFound}");
```

---

You can use a `foreach` loop

```
foreach (var element in array) // loop to the end of the array
{
    if (element == value) // comparison
    {
        isFound = true;    // we found
        break;             // We can exit the loop early
    }
}

// Write our results
Console.WriteLine($"Found = {isFound}");
```

---

You can use a `while` loop

```
var index = 0;
while (index < array.Length) // loop to the end of the array
{
    if (array[index] == value) // comparison
    {
        isFound = true;        // we found
        break;                 // We can exit the loop early
    }
    index++;                   //++ is just a fancy way of saying Add one now before comparison
}

// Write our results
Console.WriteLine($"Found = {isFound}");
```

---

You can use a `do while` loop

```
var index = 0;
do // loop to the end of the array
{
    if (array[index] == value) // comparison
    {
        isFound = true;        // we found
        break;                 // We can exit the loop early
    }
} while (++index < array.Length);//  ++ is just a fancy way of saying Add one now before comparison
```

---

You can use `Linq` `Any`

```
// a fancy way of saying, does any element in the array match the value
isFound = array.Any(element => element == value);

// Write our results
Console.WriteLine($"Found = {isFound}");
```

---

You can use `Linq` `Contains`

```
// a fancy way of saying does the array contain your value
isFound = array.Contains(value);

// Write our results
Console.WriteLine($"Found = {isFound}");
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[for (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for)

[foreach, in (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

[while (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while)

[do (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do)

[++ Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator)

[Enumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Enumerable.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Further Reading about loops](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/loops/)

Answer (score -1):

You can easily use `List` instead of `int[]`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>(){ 2, 3, 7 };

        Console.WriteLine("List size: {0}", list.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("List has '1': {0}", list.Contains(1));
        Console.WriteLine("List has '2': {0}", list.Contains(2));
        Console.WriteLine("List has '3': {0}", list.Contains(3));
    }
}
```